# Search a String in a string (strings are input by user)

Tags: c, string

I need to write a programm where two strings are entered through the keyboard and the 1st string is searched for the 2nd and then the point where it first appeared is given out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

char in1[10000];
char in2[10000];


fgets(in1, sizeof(in1), stdin);
fgets(in2, sizeof(in2), stdin);
printf("%d", strstr(in1, in2) - in1+1);

return 0; 
}
```

I did 3 tests

```
in1=11121
in2=121
result=3 correct

in1=11121121
in2=121
result=6 wrong

in1=11121211
in2=121
result=-2348863 obviously wrong

in1=111211211211
in2=121
result=-2348879
```

I don't know why it gives out the 2nd time the sequence occurs if it occurs twice and a big negative number if it occurs thrice.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I bet that the large negative number is `-in1+1`, when `strstr` returns null after not finding anything. Please post a version of your program that actually produces the outputs you show above.

Comment: The program I posted does produce those results. And it looks like you are right. But I don't understand why it returns null if the sequence does appear in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this kind of situation it's better to use `scanf` because it truncates newlines from input while `fgets` does not. Also, you should use `%ld` since you're doing an operation with pointers (or make a cast to `int`).

The code below works for all your examples:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
     char in1[10000];
     char in2[10000];
     int i;

     scanf("%s", in1);
     scanf("%s", in2);

     char* result = strstr(in1, in2);
     if (result != NULL) printf("%ld\n", strstr(in1, in2) - in1 + 1);
     else printf("No match\n");

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is correct, the reason being, that `fgets` will include the newline read in the string, while `scanf` doesn't. Obviously the comparison in `strstr` always fails (except at the end) because of the newline character.

Comment: `scanf("%s",...` is like `gets`... (or maybe even worse)

Answer (score 0):

because function: `char *fgets(char *buf, int bufsize, FILE *stream)`
will get the `'\n'`;
so in your case,your 2nd test is `"11121121'\n'\0\"`and `"121'\n''0'",`
you can use "debug" to see the values of `in1` and `in2`

Answer (score -1):

The problem is, that you don't discard the newline characters. So, what you really searched for in your first input example was `"121\n"` and this matches the end of `"11121\n"`. And the first match of `"121\n"` in `"11121121\n"` is at 6-th position.

What happens with "`11121211\n`" and `"121\n"` is: There is no match and `strstr` returns 0.

```
int main() {
    char in1[10000];
    char in2[10000];
    fgets(in1, sizeof(in1), stdin);
    { /* Delete the newline character if there is one. */
        size_t len = strlen(in1);
        if(in1[len-1]=='\n') in1[len-1] = 0;
    }
    fgets(in2, sizeof(in2), stdin);
    {
        size_t len = strlen(in2);
        if(in2[len-1]=='\n') in2[len-1] = 0;
    }
    char *match = strstr(in1, in2);
    if(match) {
        printf("%td\n", match-in1+1);
        // t is the conversion specifier for ptrdiff_t
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, don't forget to check the return values of `fgets`. Also note, that `len-1` is an invalid offset in case `len` is 0. So you must handle this either.